# Use substring against a file with varied length strings

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file which contains values like

```
10AB1CD1278A 
10AB5CD12578HJI
```

Using the below

```
set var=10AB2CDEFG12345
set "var=%var:~2,4%"
echo %var%
```

Expected answer "AB1C".Which is 4 characters after the digit 10.
Since the values within the file are of varied length the above doesnt work for all the values contained.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Have edited the question.The expected result from the code should have been AB1C followed by AB5C and so on but in a recursive way since the input is contained in a file.

Comment: And what is the actual result? This information should be offered up front.

Comment: Like I have mentioned it the expected result should be AB1C followed by AB5C.I run it only for one element and get the expected output.My concern is how do I run it against a file which has elements like 10AB1CD1278A,10AB5CD12578HJI and so on.I should be able to create a another file by extracting only the 4 characters post the digit "10".

Comment: OK, I think I got it -- English issue. "Since the values within the file are of varied length the above doesnt work" implies that there is a problem related to the length of some values, while the real problem is that you want to make this work in a loop -- right? "varied length" threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after looking at you comments I think we can understand that you want to create a batch file which goes through every line in a text file and present to you the desired series of four letters. If so, very easy. Run this in the same directory, with the file saved as input.txt

#### Code :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (input.txt) do (
set var=%%a
set "var=!var:~2,4!"
echo !var!
)
```

Note: I kept the commands as they were incase you intended to do something else with it.

Hope this helped, Mona